# node js mongoose filter result according to date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ive been stuck in a situation where I need to fetch records from mongo db according to date

so i have `start_date` as `2017-08-20` and `end_date` as `2017-08-21` coming from the front end. 
I have a record like this

```
{
            "success": 1,
            "total": 1,
            "request": 0,
            "response": "17",
            "username": "comp1",
            "timestamp": "2017-08-21T05:13:32.000Z"
        }
```

now i want to run the mongoose query like this

```
Model.find(query)
```

from node js code so that i get the data from `2017-08-20` starting from `00:00` to `2017-08-21` ending to `23:59`

need to know what `query` i need to put to get the records of the selected date, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a query like this:

```
Model.find({
  timestamp: {
    $gte: ISODate("2017-08-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2017-08-21T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
}, function(err, docs) {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: ISODate is not defined?

Comment: @RehanShah can you import this from Mongoose? If not, this might be due to a newer version. Take a look at this question for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848314/isodate-is-not-defined