# Count Documents based on admission date in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

## I'm counting the documents based on admission date of students by #using mongoose library

## I have tried with new Date() and new Date().toISOString()

```
parameters = {
          "startDate": "2013-01-01T00:00:00+05:30",
          "endDate": "2013-12-31T23:59:59+05:30"
        }

var prom = student.find({
     admissiondate: {
         $gte: new Date(parameters.startDate),
         $lte: new Date(parameters.endDate)
        }
        }, { _id: 0, admissionno: 1, firstname: 1, lastname: 1 })
```

```
#for date to isostring
var prom = student.find({
           admissiondate: {
               $gte: new Date(parameters.startDate).toISOString(),
               $lte: new Date(parameters.endDate).toISOString()
           }
       }, { _id: 0, admissionno: 1, firstname: 1, lastname: 1 })
```

Expected: a number (ex: 12)

ERRORS:

## for new Date()

CastError: Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "admissiondate" for model "students"

## for new Date().toISOString()

RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString ()

Comment: if I take your `parameters` and run this in the browser console: `var y = new Date(parameters.startDate);` it gives me `Mon Dec 31 2012 19:30:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)`

Comment: Cast to date should work...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `new Date()` to `ISODate()`

```
var prom = student.find({
           admissiondate: {
               $gte: ISODate(parameters.startDate).toISOString(),
               $lte: ISODate(parameters.endDate).toISOString()
           }
       }, { _id: 0, admissionno: 1, firstname: 1, lastname: 1 })
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4TbefD9_UOc)

Comment: javascript will say ISODate is not defined

Comment: here is the link about it -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8848314/9037185