# Mongoose query on date in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve all of my charts data with a query on date attribute but it returns all of charts data and not good results.

Model

```
charts: [
        {
            date: {
                type: Date,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    ],
```

My query

```
Model.findById({ _id: '5f47f7d65ff89941ecbc8340', 'charts.date': { $gte: '2020-01-15' } })
```

I want to retrieve all charts elements whose date is greater than '2020-01-15'.

Comment: Can you add what it returns?

Comment: is your field 'Date' of type ISODate or string in mongoDb? Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848314/isodate-is-not-defined

Comment: [{
      open: 48.22,
      close: 50.47,
      high: 49.77,
      low: 49,
      volume: 51353,
      date: 2007-06-05T00:00:00.000Z
    },
    ... 3451 more items
  ]

Comment: My query working with a no array field but with charts which is an array of objects, it not working! I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` function and its related friends operate on documents.  The query you've submitted will match on any document with the matching `_id` and a `charts.date` in the specified range, and return the entire document.

If you can get by with just the first matching element from the chart array, you could use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection) in a projection.

If you need to get all matching elements, you'll need to use aggregation with a `$filter`.

Comment: I tried this but I have no results ...

Model.aggregate([
        { $match: { symbol: 'CW8' } },
        { $unwind: '$charts' },
        { $match: { 'charts.date': { $gte: '2020-01-12' } } },
        { $group: { _id: '$_id', charts: { $push: '$charts.date' } } }
    ])

Comment: Are the dates actually stored as strings?

Comment: Dates are stored as ISODate: 2020-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00

Comment: The you'll need to use an ISODate with `$gte` in order to match.

Comment: I tried { $gte: new Date('2020-01-12').toISOString() }, it's not working either

Comment: `toISOString()` returns string, not `ISODate`